# How to extract the first x-megabyte from a large file in unix/linux?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, dd

I have a large file which I am only interested in the first couple of megabytes in the head.

How do I extract the first x-megabyte from a large file in unix/linux and put it into a seperate file?

(I know the split command can split files into many pieces. And using bash scripts I can erase the pieces I don't want. I would prefer a easier way)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218912/linux-command-like-cat-to-read-a-specified-quantity-of-characters) talks about the same issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Head works with binary files and the syntax is neater than dd.

```
head -c 2M input.file > output.file
```

Tail works the same way if you want the end of a file.

Answer (score 18):

E.g.

```
 dd if=largefile count=6 bs=1M > largefile.6megsonly
```

The `1M` spelling assumes GNU dd. Otherwise, you could do

```
 dd if=largefile count=$((6*1024)) bs=1024 > largefile.6megsonly
```

This again assumes bash-style *arithmetic* *evaluation*.

Answer (score 6):

On a Mac (Catalina) the `head` and `tail` commands don't seem to take modifiers like m (mega) and g (giga) in upper or lower case, but will take a large integer byte count like this one for 50 MB

```
head -c50000000 inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the command dd. You can use ["man dd"](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) to get main ideas of it.