# Reverse of `copy /b prog.exe + zip.zip out.exe`

Tags: windows, copy, command-prompt

What would be the reverse command of something like(I'm ok if the code needs to be changed slightly to make it possible to detect where the file should be split).

```
copy /b prog.exe + zip.zip out.exe
```

I would like to get the zip back out from the original combination.

I would like the program to be in command prompt, powershell, node.js, or c if possible(python I guess could work).

My guess is that you might need a file size appended to the end like so `copy /b prog.exe + zip.zip + progsize out.exe`.

Comment: Appending `progsize` is good way to do it. It looks simple to code. Just do it.

Answer (score 1):

Some `C` coding (or any other language, actually) will provide you with what you want. The information you need is already stored in the header of your `prog.exe`.

Namely - the number of 512-byte blocks and the size of the last block (bytes 04-05 and 02-03 respectively).

With that you can calculate the offset of a byte right after your `prog.exe`:

```
extra_data_start = exe.blocks_in_file * 512L;
if (exe.bytes_in_last_block)
  extra_data_start -= (512 - exe.bytes_in_last_block);
```

For more info see the [EXE Format reference](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/exe/) which has a C-style `struct` defined for your needs as well.

**Update**
For the Windows `portable executable` the procedure is similar. You can easily find the details on its format on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) and write your code accordingly.

Comment: Those two values will just take you to the end of the DOS stub, after which comes the actual PE. So, this answer is pretty incomplete. We don't give teh codez, but we also should not redirect people to outside resources.

Answer (score 1):

Here is attempt of constructing the combined exe and zip(from original files).  7z is required to get this to work.

```
(* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218912/linux-command-like-cat-\
to-read-a-specified-quantity-of-characters *)
exe = "NegativeScreen.exe";
stream = OpenRead[exe, BinaryFormat -> True];
BinaryWrite["NS2.exe", 
  BinaryReadList[stream, "Byte", FileByteCount[exe]
   ]];
BinaryWrite["NS2.exe",
  PadLeft[ToCharacterCode@ToString@FileByteCount[exe], 10, 48]
  ];
Close[stream];
Close["NS2.exe"];

SetDirectory["C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\"];

files = {"$.csv"};
zip = "test.zip";
Run@"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\" a " <> zip <> " " <> 
  StringJoin@Riffle[{"t", "b"}, " "];
Run["copy /b prog.exe + zip.zip out.exe"];
```

and extracting the content

```
old = "NS2.exe";
stream = OpenRead[old, BinaryFormat -> True];
Skip[stream, "Byte", combined = (FileByteCount[old] - 10)];
exeBytes = 
  FromDigits@FromCharacterCode@BinaryReadList[stream, "Byte", 10];
Close[stream];
stream = OpenRead[old, BinaryFormat -> True];
content = BinaryReadList[stream, "Byte", exeBytes];
content2 = BinaryReadList[stream, "Byte", combined - Length@content]
Close[stream];
(* BinaryWrite[old, content,"Byte"];
Close[old]; *)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should copy the data over using node.js I believe.

```
fs = require('fs');

file1=fs.createReadStream('./file1',{ flags: 'r',  encoding: "binary",});
file2=fs.createReadStream('./file2',{ flags: 'r',  encoding: "binary",});

fs.stat('./file1', function (err, stats) {
    fs.writeFileSync("./size", stats.size);
    file3=fs.createReadStream('./size',{ flags: 'r',  encoding: "binary",});
    dest=fs.createWriteStream('./destinationFile',{ flags: 'w',  encoding: "binary"});

    file1.pipe(dest, { end: false });
    file2.pipe(dest, { end: false });
    file3.pipe(dest, { end: false }); 
});
```

And the `test.js` file.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.stat('calibre-portable.exe', function (err, stats) {
    console.log(stats.size);
  });
```